# How to "use" a module at run time

Tags: linux, perl

I am in the process of developing a module that will call a Perl modules on specific conditions.

And the logic will be this:

```
$var = "db_tk";

if ( $var =~ /db/ ) {
    use dbi;
}

if ( $var =~ /tk/ ) {
    use tk;
}
```

I am not able to run them at run time using `require`.

Comment: Why are you unable to use `require`?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I think you now have specific answers to your question, but for more on this subject see Neil Bowers article on ["CPAN modules that (can) load other modules"](http://neilb.org/reviews/module-loading.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
use Module;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
    require Module;
    import Module;
}
```

so you want

```
 require Module;
 import Module;
```

Except importing from a module at run-time makes no sense. So you either want

```
# Conditionally load modules at runtime.
# Gotta use fully-qualified names to call provided functions.

my $var = "db_tk";

require DBI if $var =~ /db/;
require Tk  if $var =~ /tk/;
```

or

```
# Conditionally load modules at compile-time.

BEGIN {
    my $var = "db_tk";

    if ($var =~ /db/) { require DBI; import DBI; }
    if ($var =~ /tk/) { require Tk;  import Tk;  }
}
```

The [if module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if) can be used to simplify the latter:

```
# Conditionally load modules at compile-time.

my $var;
BEGIN {
    $var = "db_tk";
}

use if $var =~ /db/, 'DBI';
use if $var =~ /tk/, 'Tk';
```

Answer (score 8):

*"I am not able to run them on runtime using "require""* Yes, you are. Anywhere that `use` works, `require` will also work: `use` calls `require`

Assuming that you meant to use the standard CPAN modules `DBI` and `Tk`, and not `dbi` and `tk`, then you need this

```
if ( $var =~ /db/ ) {
    use DBI;
}

if ( $var =~ /tk/ ) {
    use Tk;
}
```

Or, as long as you have previously defined `$var` in a `BEGIN` block, you can use the `if` pragma

```
use if $var =~ /db/, DBI;
use if $var =~ /tk/, Tk;
```